# If $\text{Mod}_{R}$ and $\text{Mod}_{S}$ are equivalent, then $R$ and $S$ have the same simple modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules

Let $R$ and $S$ be (unital, associative) rings. If $\text{Mod}_{R}$ and $\text{Mod}_{S}$ are equivalent categories, then is it true that $R$ and $S$ have the same amount of isomorphism classes of simple modules?

Since an equivalence of categories preserves 'all categorical properties': an equivalent question would be? Is being a simple module a categorical property? Intuitively, I would guess so because Schur's lemma allows us to say something about morphisms from and to a simple module but I'm struggling with making everything precise.

Comment: What have you tried? I would try exactly the same direction, but I am not aware of Schur Lemmas if $R, S$ are not algebras over an algebraically closed field. What is it about?

Comment: However, I would definitely say so if the equivalence is exact, so that the grothendieck (semi)groups are the same and you can recover simple objects as "indecomposable" in the grothendieck (semi)groups. Also, maybe assuming we have a finite number of simple modules would be meaningful here? Would you be satisfied with this?

Comment: @AndreaMarino Well, if $M$ is a simple module and $M \to N$ is a morphism of modules, then you can look at its kernel and conclude it is either $0$ or everything. Thus any morphism from a simple module to any other module is either $0$ or injective (= monomorphism). Similar remarks hold if you put the simple module in the codomain.

Comment: @AndreaMarino I do not want to make such an assumption.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about the Schur lemma that compares the morphism with $\lambda Id $, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the morphism. You have an answer btw :) just to say, the notion you have introduced is called Morita equivalence

Comment: @AndreaMarino Yes, this question popped up in a Morita-context context ;)

Comment: @Andrea: to take the Grothendieck group you have in mind you need to restrict attention to modules of finite length, so you need to show that having finite length is a categorical property. It is, but that depends on simplicity being a categorical property. Also, Schur's lemma in an abelian category says that the endomorphism ring of a simple object is a division ring.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. It turns out I got more answers than the OP XD @Qiaochu Yuan: I see the point. I am probably overused to think about this context in (finite dimensional) representation theory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  A simple module is an object $A$ of $\mathrm{Mod}_R$ which is not a zero object such that every monic morphism $B\to A$ from any other object $B$ either factors through a zero object or is an isomorphism.  (In concrete terms, this says any injective homomorphism to $A$ is either $0$ or surjective, so every submodule of $A$ is either trivial or all of $A$.)  Each part of this definition is preserved by an equivalence of categories, so an equivalence of categories $\mathrm{Mod}_R\to \mathrm{Mod}_S$ sends simple modules to simple modules.

Comment: Small note (for the OP) is that in other contexts "simple = no subobjects" is not quite the right definition and it makes more sense to take "simple = no quotients" (say, a nonzero object $S$ such that every regular epimorphism $S \to M$ is either zero or an isomorphism). For example, in commutative rings "simple = no quotients" produces the fields, but "simple = no subobjects" produces the rings $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n$.